Type importing in dynamically loaded modules
I want to dynamically load a module from within a package and to import objects from the package into this module. However, I am getting an inconsistency in the name spaces what the types is concerned.
My package files are in directory pkg:
pkg:
__init__.py, main.py, commands.py, queries.py

and the module to be loaded, run.py, resides in some other place,my_directory.
main.py is the main module, it dynamically loads run.py:
import importlib.util
import sys

script_file = 'my_directory/run.py'
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('my_script', script_file)
mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[script_file] = mod
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)

commands.py:
from queries import report, Format

def list_data(fmt: Format = Format.ASCII):
    report(fmt)

queries.py:
from enum import auto, Enum

class Format(Enum):
    ASCII = auto()
    PYTHON = auto()

def report(fmt):
    if fmt == Format.PYTHON:
        print('Format is Python')
    else:
        print('Same values:', fmt == Format.PYTHON)
        print('Same types:', type(fmt) == type(Format.PYTHON))
        print(f'Formats: {fmt}, {Format.PYTHON}')
        print('Module of Format:', Format.__module__)
        print('Module of fmt:', fmt.__module__)

___init.py:
from .queries import Format
from .commands import list_data

and run.py:
from pkg import list_data, Format

list_data(Format.PYTHON)

I would expect Format is Python to be printed, but the else branch is executed, and I am getting the following output:
Same values: False
Same types: False
Formats: Format.PYTHON, Format.PYTHON
Module of Format: queries
Module of fmt: pkg.queries

which indicates that the types of Format.PYTHON have different name spaces and don't compare.
How should I modify my code to get the expected behavior?
I apologize for the lengthy description but I could not succeed to reproduce the problem on a smaller example.

Could you provide what your full expected output is?

I am getting Format is Python in the terminal. I wasn't able to get run.py to run outside of the folder pkg/, so I moved it in the folder and imported from there.

The expected outcome is Format is Python

I found the problem. The correct import statement in __init__.py (note the absence of dots before queries and commands.py) is:
from queries import Format
from commands import list_data


I noticed in the report(fmt) method, your goal was to compare values. Either try to use IntEnum so you don't have to use the Enum.value method, or just use Enum.value.
Example 1 (Enum.value)
from enum import auto, Enum

class Format(Enum):
    ASCII = auto()
    PYTHON = auto()

def report(fmt):
    if fmt.value == Format.PYTHON.value:
        print('Format is Python')
    else:
        print('Same values:', fmt == Format.PYTHON)
        print('Same types:', type(fmt) == type(Format.PYTHON))
        print(f'Formats: {fmt}, {Format.PYTHON}')
        print('Module of Format:', Format.__module__)
        print('Module of fmt:', fmt.__module__)

Example 2 (IntEnum)
from enum import auto, IntEnum

class Format(IntEnum):
    ASCII = auto()
    PYTHON = auto()

def report(fmt):
    if fmt == Format.PYTHON:
        print('Format is Python')
    else:
        print('Same values:', fmt == Format.PYTHON)
        print('Same types:', type(fmt) == type(Format.PYTHON))
        print(f'Formats: {fmt}, {Format.PYTHON}')
        print('Module of Format:', Format.__module__)
        print('Module of fmt:', fmt.__module__)


This is just a workaroud. It is comletey fine to compare two Enum values for equality.

Is it working though?

Yes, it does work.
